# Pdf content is not rendering correctly after redaction applied using itext5

Tags: java, itext

I am using following code.

```
public class RemoveContentInRectangle {
public static final String SRC = "resources/pdfs/pdffile.pdf";
public static final String DEST = "resources/pdfs/pdfnew.pdf";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    File file = new File(SRC);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    new RemoveContentInRectangle().manipulatePdf(SRC, DEST);
}

public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    List<PdfCleanUpLocation> cleanUpLocations = new ArrayList<PdfCleanUpLocation>();
    for(int i=1; i<= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++){
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(144.98572f, 655.74976f, 257.91428f, 670.322f);
        cleanUpLocations.add(new PdfCleanUpLocation(i, rect, BaseColor.GRAY));          
    }
    try{            
        PdfCleanUpProcessor cleaner = new PdfCleanUpProcessor(cleanUpLocations, stamper);
        cleaner.cleanUp();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}    

}
```

I am getting missing text in output pdf file. Please see screenshots.

[original pdf file screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLAKQ.jpg)

[output pdf file screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEd48.jpg)

redacted area is with gray rectangle and characters are missing from all over the document.

How could i resolve this issue?

Comment: Which version of iText are you using? Clean up is recent functionality. It has been improved with every new version. If you're not using iText 5.5.9, don't expect an answer other than: upgrade to iText 5.5.9 (or to iText 7 and the pdfSweep add-on).

Comment: I am using iText 5.5.9

Comment: What happens if you use iText 7 and pdfSweep?